# Transform original bitmap on android

Tags: android

So, I'm using this library https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views to add "MultiTouchListener" feature to my ImageView. Basically I let user to modify a photo to his needs using rotation, scale and translation. Now the only problem is how to save it. I did it like this:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageContainer.getWidth(), imageContainer.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    imageContainer.draw(canvas);
```

It works, but image is not big enough - it's as big as view on phone so it depends on screen resolution. And I want to "apply" these transformations on given bitmap with full size. And I want transformed image to look like on screen (so it'll need to crop everything out of screen)

I tried the following:

```
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, imageView.getMatrix(), paint);
```

But it doesn't look as expected.

User screen:

[image]

And output image (without cropping, because I don't want which side I should crop):

[image]

How can I fix this? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, definitely not perfect but should give you a good start :

In this, `container` refers to the view that contains the transformed `ImageView`, the phone case on your screenshot and `src` the raw source bitmap.

- First, you need to compute the desired width and height of the output bitmap, i.e the size it would be to make the image fit in it while keeping the ratio of the container :

  ```
  float containerWidth = containerView.getWidth();
  float containerHeight = containerView.getHeight();

  float srcWidth = src.getWidth();
  float srcHeight = src.getHeight();

  float containerRatio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
  float srcRatio = srcWidth / srcHeight;

  float outputWidth, outputHeight;

  if(srcRatio > containerRatio) { //fits in width
          outputWidth = srcWidth;
          outputHeight = srcWidth / containerRatio;
  }
  else if(srcRatio < containerRatio) { //fits in height
          outputHeight = srcHeight;
          outputWidth = srcHeight * containerRatio;
  }
  else {
      outputWidth = srcWidth;
      outputHeight = srcHeight;
  }
  ```
- Apply the ratio between container width/height and output width/height to the translation part of the matrix that hold the transformation that the user did

  ```
  float containerToOutputRatioWidth = outputWidth / containerWidth;
  float containerToOutputRatioHeight = outputHeight / containerHeight;

  float[] values = new float[9];
  transformedImageView.getMatrix().getValues(values);
  values[2] = values[2] * containerToOutputRatioWidth;
  values[5] = values[5] * containerToOutputRatioHeight;
  Matrix outputMatrix = new Matrix();
  outputMatrix.setValues(values);
  ```
- Draw the output bitmap as you were doing with the correct size (outputWidth, outputHeight) and matrix (outputMatrix).

  ```
  Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(outputWidth), Math.round(outputHeight), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
  canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  canvas.drawBitmap(src, outputMatrix, paint);
  ```

[image: Demo].

**Warnings**

You should be careful about memory allocation, this code will lead to allocate some massive bitmaps, you should implement some kind of limit that get along with your needs. (Also do allocation and drawing in background)

You might need to do some adjustment depending on where you place the image in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! I tried your method, but somehow output bitmap is not in the right place. http://pastebin.com/6e0KEEBz check out my code. You can easily swap between my old method and your method to see the output.

Comment: Its kinda not relevant without your layout and assets files, here is a more complete and easy to get running version of the code in the answer : https://gist.github.com/meynety/387d01570be2066c2b68. As I said in the answer, you might need to do some adjustments depending on your layout…

Comment: Yeah your code works great. I've found the issue - it was settings size of imageView - it made it look different. I just removed that line. Now I'm struggling with last step - make initial image to look-like aspect fill (no blank space after intialilly loading photo). I tried android:scaleType="centerCrop" in your example, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: As I said, the code needs some adjustments depending on how you place the image in the first place (works with `fitStart`), probably because `ImageView#getMatrix()` only contain the transformations of the view, not the drawable inside the view. I'll post you some code later. Also do not miss the `adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Comment: Yeah I've added adjustViewBounds. Looking for your code :)